# Glass GDK : onSensorChanged not called

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have an activity with :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, GestureDetector.BaseListener
```

I implement the functions

```
@Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    Log.d("MOTION", "MOTION DETECTED");
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Log.d("MOTION", "SENSOR DETECTED");
}
```

onGenericMotionEvent works fine, but onSensorChanged is never called, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you properly registered your `Activity` as a listener within your `SensorManager`? You should checkout the [`Compass`](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-compass-sample) sample which makes use of some of the sensors on Glass.

The class you'd be interested in is the [`OrientationManager`](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-compass-sample/blob/master/src/com/google/android/glass/sample/compass/OrientationManager.java):

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
```